How to share a "global variable" from a static library across DLL's
We are working on breaking apart a large application that has a main exe plus many DLL's/so's.  We want some DLL's to build independently. As part of doing this, we want to move some code from DLL's to static libraries so that each component is a single DLL.
The problem is that we have some low-level global variables.  Two examples: Application name (string) and a container of custom exception handlers (callback function).
I do not want "registration" functions in each DLL where the main code calls some function and provides the global.  This is fragile and doesn't work during startup when initializing global variables.
I think that the solution is to use some sort of named memory block that each DLL can find.  I can use a named memory mapped file (with the pid as part of the name) on Windows with CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,...,szName) and mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS) on Linux. However, I believe that other processes could discover and mess with the memory.
Are CreateFileMapping and mmap the best way to accomplish this memory discoveryfrom within the same process? We're using C++20.

global states are root of all evil in software, so it would be best if you would abandon this solution.

Agreed.  If this 10 million line program had not been written starting in 1982, we would do that. :)

I'm confused about this line: "we want to move some code from DLL's to static libraries so that each component is a single DLL.". Static libraries are not dll-s. Or did you mean you have a dll which is statically linked (dll is implicitly loaded before main).

There are many DLLs/SOs involved.  The lowest one, call it core.dll, is used by virtually every other dll.  That's our first target, we want to make that static, so each other dll will get an independent copy.
Then, some of the functions in the static core.lib need to have a true global variable, across all dll's.

What's the benefit of making the core static?

Some of these dll's become python wheels and distributing the secondary dll's is a bit of a pain.  Also, we are working to clean up code so there aren't so many dll's.  However, some dll's are truly add-ons to a main product and need to be demand loaded.  They still need access to core. Even after we convert virtually everything to be static, we still will have these plugins.

What's the difficulty with embedding the dlls into the wheel? (I'm not entirely sure how our wheel build process works, but there's some standard step to embed the dlls; maybe auditwheel repair does this, not sure.)

I wouldn't attempt to have a "true global variable, across all dll's".    If there really must be a global, isolate it to exactly one DLL that either (1) exports a function which returns a pointer or reference, and call it from other DLLs as needed  or (2)  export functions that other DLLs can call in order to access/modify state of that global.    In other words, export an interface that all DLLs (except the one that owns the global) must use to [indirectly] access the global.
